# Running conda command in command line

Tags: command-line, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install the MLxtend library for python. The command to do this should be simply typing:

```
conda install mlxtend --channel conda-forge.
```

I tried running it in the command prompt right when it opened up (which was `C:\Users\Ben`. When this didn't work, I changed directories to `C:\anaconda\anaconda3\scripts` and ran the same command there. It again didn't work so I tried to update anaconda by running: `conda update conda`. This again didn't work and I am not sure exactly what is going on that is causing the error. Everything on Google and everywhere else hasn't worked so I'm hoping y'all know how to fix this.

Error I'm getting:

```
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Collecting package metadata: failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))
```

Comment: Does this solution work for your problem: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8273 ? Also, try running `execstack -c libcrypto.so.1.0.0` per https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6064#issuecomment-334080665

Comment: Please use the anaconda command prompt and report if that solves your problem